React native :Unable to resolve module http
Im using react native cli with typescript.
when project running i got the error Unable to resolve module http from \miniget\dist\index.js: http could not be found within the project or in these directories
enter image description here
im ctrl+click http require and it be link to declare module.
what can i config project or setup anymore.
here is my config tsconfig file
{
  "extends": "@react-native/typescript-config/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6", 
    "module": "commonjs",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "node_modules",
    "./@types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}

Can anybody help me solve this issue.
